# Questions that shouldn't be closed

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Sometimes, questions are on their way to being closed because of a widespread misconception among SO users.  Sometimes these questions are good fits for SO in spite of said widespread misconception.  You might come across them when they have 1-4 close votes.  There's no "don't close vote" and it seems you can't cast a reopen vote until it's collected *five* of them.  How are we, SO users, meant to deal with questions in this unfortunate situation?

Comment: Do you have any examples of such questions?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107855/building-the-tetrahedra-of-a-set-of-random-points-tetrahedralization is one right now.  This situation comes up every now and then.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the topic so I can't vote but from the looks of it that can gather closevotes for asking for external resources or being a better fit for something like cs.se. Perhaps you can clarify why you think it shouldn't be closed?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: It fits within the help centre guidelines.  (Certainly the question could use a slight wording change, but it shouldn't be *closed* over that.)

Comment: The way I see it, there is one question: *I would be interested in : algorithms, reading suggestions, actual libraries*. How is this not a pure resource request?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: There, I fixed it.  It now reads "How can I do this?" and is on-topic by the book, too.  Notice that (1) the meaning of the question has not changed, and (2) the set of reasonable answers has not changed.

Answer (score 1):

You’re supposed to comment, explaining the misconception and why it shouldn’t be closed. If you’re convincing enough, there will be no more close votes, and the existing close votes will either expire or be retracted. If it does get closed, you can vote to reopen and hopefully the comment will convince others to do the same.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of what current procedure is.  But why can't I cast the reopen vote preemptively?  Why do I have to monitor the question and wait for it to get closed?  Usually I just don't care enough, and if the question gets closed, it's not my loss.

Comment: @tmyklebu: I answered your question in its current form. If it is really a feature request, you should add the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag and explain what you think should be changed rather than asking what should be done under the status quo.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you did as well as you could.  But this procedure doesn't solve the problem; the question gets closed and I don't care enough to find it again and cast a reopen vote.

Comment: @icktoofay That has a bit of history to it on the old MSO which is now at MSE: [How about a “Vote not to close” option to counter the “Vote to close”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close) and all its [linked questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/125?lq=1).

Comment: @MichaelT: Great, so it's a dupe, but the dupe is on another site.  Seems I can't close this as a dupe.